# Compact list conversion using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

This is my code:

```
 List<bool> results1 = new List<bool>();
 List<int> items1 = ...;
 foreach (var item in items1)
     results1.Add((item >= 1600 && item <= 5000));
```

I'm sure this can be compacted into one line, but how?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you done any introductory research into LINQ to see what operations it has that might be capable of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`results1 = items1.Select(i => i >= 1600 && i <= 5000).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

[ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't change the original list. In order to make this one-liner, you probably should substitute `items1` with the code `...` where you get your items, if you are not using it somewhere else.

```
 List<bool> results1 = items1.ConvertAll(i => i >= 1600 && i <= 5000);
```

Comment: I was aware of the Array.ConvertAll method but I didn't even realise that there was a List<T>.ConvertAll method.